# How to connect from vs 2008 to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2005

How can I connect from vs2005 to remote Sql Server (Sql Server 2008 ) when I connect 
I have amessage mean that is not support connecting from VS2005 to Sql Server 2008

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with C#, you should consider changing your tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're running Visual Studio 2005 SP1 and then install this:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e1109aef-1aa2-408d-aa0f-9df094f993bf&displaylang=en

You won't be able to design tables but you'll be able to amend the data and create/edit Stored Procedures.